# "ObjC declarations may only appear in global scope" Social.framework error

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, xcode4, social-framework

I am trying to import `<Social/Social.h>` in my project, but when I try to run, I get the error `Objective-C declarations may only appear in global scope` in the two files `SLRequest.h` and `SLComposeViewController.h`. A thing to be mentioned is that the `Social.framework` remains in Frameworks group in the project navigator even though I've deleted it *which I think is the cause of the problem*. I tried to remove and re-add it from *Link Binary With Libraries*, but I had no luck. I tried to use it in another project and it runs with successfully.

---

Update: `#import` is above `@implementation`. This is exactly my code:

```
#import "flatGreenColor.h" 
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> 
#import <Social/Social.h>

@end 

@interface SettingsController1 () 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* settingTitles; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* settingsElements; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* boldFontName; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* onColor; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* offColor; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* dividerColor; 

@end
```

Comment: Where exactly is your `#import` versus your `@implementation`?

Comment: `#import` is above `@ implementation` This is exactly my code:

`#import "flatGreenColor.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

@end
@interface SettingsController1 ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* settingTitles;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* settingsElements;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* boldFontName;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* onColor;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* offColor;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* dividerColor;
@end`

Comment: What's that `@end` doing after the `#import <Social/Social.h>`? Have you possibly inadvertently omitted an `@end` from `flatGreenColor.h`?

Comment: Oh, it was exactly like what you said, I forgot to add `@end` in `flatGreenColor.h` which is why I was getting an error telling me to add that `@end` *I wasn't informed about all that*. Thank you so much, Tommy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error was caused as I was adding an `@end` after `#import <Social/Social.h>`. I forgot to add it in another `header` which I was importing to my `.m`. The answer was provided in the comments by @Tommy